# Prob. 7 (c), Sec. 28, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Example of a shrinking map that is not a contraction

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification, contraction-operator

Here is Prob. 7, Sec. 28, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. If $f$ satisfies the condition
>   $$ d\big( f(x), f(y) \big) < d(x, y) $$
>   for all $x, y \in X$ with $x \neq y$, then $f$ is called a *shrinking map*. If there is a number $\alpha < 1$ such that
>   $$ d \big( f(x), f(y) \big) \leq \alpha d(x, y) $$
>   for all $x, y \in X$, then $f$ is called a *contraction*. A *fixed point* of $f$ is a point $x$ such that $f(x) = x$.
>
> (a) If $f$ is a contraction and $X$ is compact, show $f$ has a unique fixed point. [*Hint:* Define $f^1 = f$ and $f^{n+1} = f \circ f^n$. Consider the intersection $A$ of the sets $A_n = f^n(X)$.]
>
> (b) Show more generally that if $f$ is a shrinking map and $X$ is compact, then $f$ has a unique fixed point. [*Hint:* Let $A$ be as before. Given $x \in A$, choose $x_n$ so that $x = f^{n+1}\left(x_n\right)$. If $a$ is the limit of some subsequence of the sequence $y_n = f^n \left( x_n \right)$, show that $a \in A$ and $f(a) = x$. Conclude that $A = f(A)$, so that $\mathrm{diam}\, A = 0$.]
>
> (c) Let $X = [0, 1]$. Show that $f(x) = x - x^2/2$ maps $X$ into $X$ and is a shrinking map that is not a contraction. [*Hint:* Use the mean-value theorem of calculus.]
>
> (d) The result in (a) holds if $X$ is a complete metric space, such as $\mathbb{R}$; see the exercises of \Sec. 43. The result in (b) does not: Show that the map $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \left[ x + \left( x^2 + 1 \right)^{1/2} \right]/2$ is a shrinking map that is not a contraction and has no fixed point.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137955/prob-7-a-sec-28-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-a-contraction-of-a-compact-m) is my Math SE post on Prob. 7 (a).

And, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3139704/prob-7-b-sec-28-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-a-shrinking-self-map-of-a-co) is my Math SE post on Prob. 7 (b).

Here I'll only be attempting Part (c).

My Attempt:

Part (c):

> Here 
>   $$ f(x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in [0, 1]. \tag{A} $$
>   So we obtain
>   $$ f^\prime(x) = 1 - x > 0 \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in (0, 1). \tag{B} $$
>   Thus $f$ is a *strictly increasing* function on $[0, 1]$.
>
> Suppose that there exists a real  number $\alpha$ such that 
>   $$ 0 \leq \alpha < 1  $$
>   and such that
>   $$ \big\lvert f(x) - f(y) \big\rvert \leq \alpha \, \lvert x - y \rvert \ \mbox{ for all } \ x, y \in [0, 1]. \tag{0} $$
>   So if $0  \leq x < y \leq 1$, then we obtain
>   $$ \frac{ \big\lvert f(x) - f(y) \big\rvert }{ \lvert x- y \rvert } \leq \alpha , $$
>   that is,
>   $$ \alpha \geq  \frac{ f(y) - f(x) }{ y - x } = \frac{ \left( y - \frac{y^2}{2} \right) - \left( x - \frac{x^2}{2} \right) }{ y-x } =  \frac{ 2(y-x) - \left( y^2 - x^2 \right) }{ 2(y-x) },  $$
>   Therefore
>   $$ \alpha \geq 1 - \frac{ y+x}{2} \tag{1}  $$
>   for any real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $0 \leq x < y \leq 1$.
>
> Let $x$ and $y$ be any (fixed but arbitrary) real numbers such that 
>   $$ 0 \leq x < y \leq 1. \tag{2} $$
>   Then by the Lagrange's mean-value theorem there exists a real number $c \in (x, y)$ such that
>   $$ f(y) - f(x) = f^\prime (c) (y-x), $$
>   and so
>   $$  \frac{ f(y) - f(x) }{ y- x } =  f^\prime(c) = 1-c \tag{3}.  $$
>
> So using (1) and (3) together, we obtain
>   $$ \alpha \geq 1- c, $$
>   and hence
>   $$ c \geq 1 - \alpha. \tag{4} $$
>
> However, for any real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $0 \leq x < y \leq 1$, we obtain 
>   $$ \frac{ f(y) - f(x) }{ y-x } = \frac{ \left( y - \frac{y^2 }{2} \right) - \left( x - \frac{x^2}{2} \right)  }{ y-x } = \frac{ 2(y-x) - \left( y^2 - x^2 \right) }{2 (y-x) } = 1 - \frac{y + x}{2},  $$
>   and this together with (3) above yields 
>   $$ 1 - \frac{y + x}{2} = 1 - c, $$
>   and so
>   $$ c = \frac{y + x}{2}. \tag{5} $$
>
> From (4) and (5) above, we obtain
>   $$ \frac{ x+ y}{2} \geq 1- \alpha, $$
>   and so
>   $$ \alpha \geq 1 - \frac{ x+y}{2} \tag{6} $$
>   for any real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $0 \leq x < y \leq 1$.
>
> But if we put $x = 0$ and choose $y$ so that
>   $$ 0 < y < \min \big\{ \, 1,  2 ( 1- \alpha) \, \big\}, $$
>   then 
>   $$0 <  y < 2(1-\alpha), $$
>   which implies 
>   $$ 0 < \frac{y}{2} < 1-\alpha, $$
>   and hence 
>   $$ \alpha < 1 - \frac{y}{2} = 1-\frac{x+y}{2}, $$
>   which contradicts (6) above.
>
> Thus our supposition that there exists a real number $\alpha \in [0, 1)$ for which (0) above holds is wrong. Hence $f$ is not a contraction.
>
> However, if $0 < \leq x < y \leq 1$, then there exists a real number $c \in (0, 1) \subset [0, 1]$ such that
>   $$ f(y) - f(x) = f^\prime(c) (y-x), $$
>   which implies
>   $$ \big\lvert f(x) - f(y) \big\rvert = f(y)-f(x) = (1-c)(y-x) = (1-c) \lvert x-y \rvert < \lvert x-y \rvert, $$
>   which shows that $f$ is a shrinking map.

Is this proof good enough? Or, are there issues?

Comment: You don’t need the mean value theorem for the first part: you can get it immediately from $(1)$ by setting $x=0$. Then $\alpha\ge\sup\left\{1-\frac{y}2:0<y\le 1\right\}=1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott the point is to show that there is no $\alpha \in [0, 1)$ for which (0) above holds. So is it justified to bound $\alpha$ by an expression involving $y$ at the outset?

Comment: I’m afraid that I don’t understand your question: the argument that I gave shows exactly that, i.e., that any $\alpha$ satisfying $(0)$ must be at least $1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes, you're absolutely right. I stand corrected. I got your point now. Thank you so much!

Comment: You’re welcome!